# Laravel - why is a Model's relations not being loaded?

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel 5.3 site and I think maybe I have some weird things going on due to some actions happening in API controllers and some happening in the regular controllers.

Or maybe an issue where at some times I am dealing with a Model, and sometimes with an Eloquent Collection.

The issue is, I am trying to retrieve relations on a Model and am getting null.

For instance, I have `course` Model that relates to `week` Model.

In `course` Model I get `week` items as

```
  public function weeks()
    {

        return $this->hasMany(Week::class, 'course_id');

    }
```

In backend, these relations get sent in this way:

```
$course->load('weeks')
```

All is good.

But when `course` item gets deleted and I try and take action in the `week` controller as

```
        static::deleting(function($course) { 
            $course->weeks->delete();
        });
```

$course->weeks is null. At that time I see in the database that all is good and this `course` items does indeed have a `week` item related, but `$course` shows 0 relations.

So something odd is happening where `$course->webinars` is not grabbing the `week` items related.

Is there something that I am fundamentally doing wrong? Maybe it is because in the models I have these sorts of statements:

```
protected $table = 'Week';
```

Are these preventing the relations from being pulled? I always thought that is I had some function in a model that returns relations that those relations would always be available when I use syntax `$course->weeks`.

Ideas?

Thanks again,

Answer (score 0):

You can simply setup migrations to automatically delete from weeks if you delete a course, provided you have foreign key relationship.

If you have a column course_id in weeks table then add this into your migration

```
$table->foreign('course_id')
      ->references('id')->on('courses')
      ->onDelete('cascade')
```

Comment: Yeah that is how things are set up but it is making it difficult for me to have deleted events triggered on items that are deleted by cascade.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Observers.   In your AppServiceProvider, first register the observer.

```
public function boot()
{
     Course::observe(CourseObserver::class);
}

Now, add an Observer class.

class CourseObserver
{
    public function deleting(Course $course)
    {
         $course->weeks()->delete();
    }
}
```